# Move an HTML tag up two levels using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following HTML layout

```
<div id="wizard-step-content" class="wizard-step-content row-fluid">
    <div id="accordion">
        <div>
            <article class="orderwizard-module orderwizard-module-proxy-addresses-opc">
                <h3 class="section-header">Enter Shipping Address</h3>
                <article class="orderwizard-module orderwizard-module-proxy-addresses-opc module-rendered">
                   other tags
           </article>
           </article>
       </div>
        <div>
            <article class="orderwizard-module orderwizard-payment">
                <article class="orderwizard-module orderwizard-module-payment">
                   other tags no H3
                </article>
                <h3 class="section-header">Enter Payment</h3>
                <article class="orderwizard-module orderwizard-module-payment">
                   other tags
                </article>
           </article>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I need to do is move the H3 tag up two levels to be between the div accordion and the div.  The problem is I have several of these under the accordion tag not just one.  The are all under a the same hierarchy   but some have other tags before the first H#. I just want to move the first H3 tag I find so if there are more than one I just want to move the first.  please help.

This code is automatically generated by a separate process so I cannot just go and modify it to render it in a different spot.

I have this script that works but it puts the H3 tag at the bottom of the `<div id="accordion">` 
tag not in the correct order.

```
$('#accordion').children('div').children('article').each(function() { $('article h3:first-child').detach().appendTo($(this).parent().parent())});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, the problem with your current code is that it targets all matching artcles's first h3 and not just the related h3 in each article.

Try this:

```
$('#accordion > div > article').each(function () {
    $(this).find('h3').insertBefore($(this).parent())
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/pkfpswbq/1/

**Notes:**

- When *moving* elements in the DOM you do not need to detach them first.

Comment: This worked great thank you very much it saved me another three hours.

Comment: @cbleile: If these type of operations take you more than 5 mins, just post another question. (They do get easier with practice) :)